# Constructor and Variable Declaration in Cpp

Tags: c++, constructor, variable-declaration

```
#include<bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;

class A{
    int x;

public:
    A(){
        x=10;
    }

    void show(){
        cout<<x<<endl;
    }
};

main(){

    A a;
    a.show();

}
```

In the `main()` function when I am declaring the variable `a` in the above way, the code works fine but if we declare the variable `A a()` compiler gives error. Why is it so? I think there is no problem regarding argument type matching. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because `A a()` is not a variable declaration but a function prototype declaration.

Answer (score 0):

C++11 and above fix this problem with universal initializers.  You are declaring a function that returns an A.  If you instead use `{}` it will work:

```
A a{};
```